# ranges::views::filter no longer compatible with std::optional, msvc v19.36

Tags: c++, range-v3, stdoptional

**Edit**: My confusion came from not understanding the `explicit` specifier and [contextual conversions to bool](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Contextual_conversions)

---

In v19.35 you could pass an invocable to `ranges::views::filter` that returned `std::optional`. In v19.36 you cant:

https://godbolt.org/z/jcfjE3var

```
auto input = std::vector<std::optional<int>>{};
#if 1
// broken v19.36, works prior
    input | ranges::views::filter([](auto pair) -> std::optional<int> { return pair; });
#else 
// works
    input | ranges::views::filter([](auto pair) -> bool { return pair; });
#endif
```

Anyone know why?

Comment: please include a [mcve] and the compiler error message in the question

Comment: You can add two compilers in godbolt, so you can see 19.35 accepting and 19.latest rejecting the same code side by side: https://godbolt.org/z/6ndr6TKz1

Comment: When code breaks after upgrading or changing compilers, my experience tells me that it is usually because of [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) in the code that just happened to *seem to* work with the old compiler - or (rarely) it's caused by a bug in the new (or old) compiler that causes it to fail to build the code (or incorrectly accepted it previously).

Comment: I have no idea why this is the case (thus comment, not answer). But if you change the lambda to: `return pair.second.has_value()`, then it compiles on 19.latest too.

Comment: @Frodyne you got my code working, so you should have given an answer. But I've changed the question now. Only God knows why `ranges::views::filter` was able to accept  `T -> std::optional` in the first place

Comment: `std::optional` is contextually convertible to `bool`, due to its `operator bool()` operator.

Comment: @TomHuntington I'm trying to find a clear definition what "predicate" is limited to for e.g. the invocable parameter for `filter`, but I can't seem to find one. Is it `T -> bool` only?

Comment: @dfrib range-v3 has their own concept for [`std::indirect_unary_predicate<Fn, Iterator>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/indirect_unary_predicate). It seems that it no longer passes this concept. I tried playing around but couldn't [get it working](https://topaz.github.io/paste/#XQAAAQARAQAAAAAAAAA6nMlWi076R8MvvqGQVBS0GR4riZfrnizPaDIPZx+7Bp4kKrvD702Z9CwNCWSiAId5Iz9SsUj9ZIWrqGp1hx7tCoUIDa3Q7+fb9t06RfJJ5WZNCulg9MNDGmJdp3C6HhWDycFTtCMS54wOf+/C0o6Ljk3CmlC3EbYMbGBNvwe/GSciK6v9cqo6ei5ddeuM4d94AP/sEh1o)

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/sPq5cnbGK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input | ranges::views::filter([](auto pair) -> bool { return pair; });` doesn't work because `std::optional<int>&` is not implicitly convertible to a `bool`. The reason it seems to work is that you don't actually use the body of the function because you don't iterate over the view. `[](std::optional<int> pair) -> bool { return pair; }` shows you the error immediately.

This is also why the `[](auto pair) -> std::optional<int>` lambda doesn't work either: To be a valid predicate for `filter`, the return type needs to be [*`boolean-testable`*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/boolean-testable), which requires it to be implicitly convertible to `bool`.

You need something like this:

```cpp
    input | ranges::views::filter([](auto pair) { return bool(pair); })
```

Comment: @TomHuntington The godbolt link you've given shows it not working, I don't think that ever worked. It is just ill formed because there is no implicit conversion from optional to bool. Also I found out why previous versions accepted optional-producing functors: ranges-v3 library's `ranges::predicate` was broken https://godbolt.org/z/7qcs9Yrx3

Comment: So I'm realizing that `[](std::optional<T> o) -> bool { return o; }` never used to work.  Still I'm not sure why `[](std::optional<T> o) -> std::optional<T> { return o; }` used to work

Comment: "ranges-v3 library's ranges::predicate was broken" thanks

Comment: I now understand the `explicit` specifier and  contextual conversions to bool. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Contextual_conversions O c++ why do you do this to me.